# Click function remove random ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

The plan for what I'm building is: You can click a button to create some houses, and they will be assigned a random ID. *(I know is not a unique ID right now).*

When you click on one of the houses that you have created you will be able to see some information about the house and a DELETE button:

```
$('.House').click(function(){
    var iDivHouseId = $(this).attr('id');
    var oHouse = findHouseId(iDivHouseId);
    $('#ShowId').text("ID: " + oHouse.getId());
    $('#ShowStreetName').text("Street name: " +oHouse.getStreetName());
    $('#ShowNumber').text("Number: " +oHouse.getNumber());
    $('#WindowDisplayPersonInfo').append('<input type="button" id="DeleteHouse" value="DELETE" />');
        $('#DeleteHouse').click(function () {
            $(?????).remove();   
        }); 
});
```

But as marked with the question marks, I don't know what I have to put in to delete the house by it's randomly created ID. I can just add the class .House, but then all houses will be deleted.

// Also, right now, several delete buttons shows when you click the house a couple of times, since it appends a new button each time. How do I replace the old button with a new, instead of just creating a new each time.

Comment: Do note that you have to use HTML5 if you want your IDs to be able start with a number. Previous versions required the ID to start with a letter.

Comment: Didn't actually know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the delete button static markup, so you don't have to append it or bind the click handler multiple times. I would then keep track of the current element id using `data()` and reference that from your click handler.

```
$('.House').click(function(){
    var iDivHouseId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#WindowDisplayPersonInfo').data('current-elem-id', iDivHouseId);
    var oHouse = findHouseId(iDivHouseId);
    $('#ShowId').text("ID: " + oHouse.getId());
    $('#ShowStreetName').text("Street name: " +oHouse.getStreetName());
    $('#ShowNumber').text("Number: " +oHouse.getNumber());
});

$('#DeleteHouse').click(function () {
    $('#' + $('#WindowDisplayPersonInfo').data('current-elem-id')).remove();   
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, this works great! Now I just have to hide the button until a house is clicked and I'm all set. :-)

Comment: For that, I would have the css of the button be `display:none;` initially, then show it in your `.House` click handler and hide it again in the `#DeleteHouse` click handler.

Answer (score 0):

By the JSFiddle, if you want to just remove the div from the right side you can try remove the launcher of the click event. To prevent errors with "this" in js, as it always changes values, you can receive a argument in your click function.

Something like this:

```
$('.House').click(function(e){
    var iDivHouseId = $(this).attr('id');
    var oHouse = findHouseId(iDivHouseId);
    $('#ShowId').text("ID: " + oHouse.getId());
    $('#ShowStreetName').text("Street name: " +oHouse.getStreetName());
    $('#ShowNumber').text("Number: " +oHouse.getNumber());
    $('#WindowDisplayPersonInfo').append('<input type="button" id="DeleteHouse" value="DELETE" />');
        $('#DeleteHouse').click(function () {
            $(oHouse).remove();   
            $(e.target).remove();
        }); 
});                  
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would wish that I could set 2 answers as accepted.